# Full History from date extracts

Tags: sql

I have a table of employee's and a record of transactions with employee ID's.

The table of Employee's contains 1 record for each employee for each role change, Team changes, Department Change etc.

I'm trying to allocate the correct Employee information for the right timeframe to the table.

Example Employee A works for Sales 15 days of the month and works for Service for another 15 Days.

2 entries exist in the Employee table, 1 old record for entry into sales Team and then a Team Swap Entry on day 15 of the month.

is it possible to populate the against each days calls the correct department that member of the team would have been working for at the time?

Comment: You assign two tables. An employee table and an activity table. .

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.